# Why does the error "find: paths must precede expression" trigger when multiple results are returned from "find"

Tags: linux, bash

Why  does the error  find: paths must precede expression: input.txt trigger when
multiple  results are returned from "find" in subprocess but  not when a single result is returned?

The dir contains three files.

```
ls
input2.txt  input.txt  input.log
```

There is only one file matching the find query and the result  can be assigned to $foo

```
$ foo=$(find . -name *.log )
echo $foo
./plot.log
```

When  `> 1`  reults are returned find throw's an error.

```
$ foo=$(find . -name *.txt )
find: paths must precede expression: input.txt
```

I don't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 15):

You need to [quote](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) special characters, because globs are [expanded](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) before running the command:

```
find . -name '*.txt'
```

To see how globbing works, try for example `echo *.txt` - it will *only* actually print `*.txt` if there are no files in the current directory ending with `.txt`.

Comment: Without the quoting the command expands to `find . -name input.txt two.txt three.txt ...` which find then sees as extra paths to search.